# Storing lambdas as members confusion

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, lambda

I was reading Scott Meyer's *Effective Modern C++* and hit the item in which he's suggesting usage of `lambda`s in place of `std::function` and `std::bind`. I understand his argument and his claim about drawbacks of `std::function` and I agreed with him.

As of today, I decided to switch to templates for storing `lambda`s (which do not need mutators). I do understand that type of every `lambda` is only known to the compiler and even two identical `lambda`s will have different types so how come the following code compiles and works just fine?

```
template<typename LambdaT>
class CaptureLambda
{
public:
    CaptureLambda(const LambdaT& fn)
        : mActionFn(fn) // initialize mActionFn to a user supplied lambda
    {}

private:
    LambdaT    mActionFn{ []{} }; // initialize mActionFn to an empty lambda
};
```

My point of confusion is that, how come `mActionFn` is default initiated to an empty lambda with a different type inside member declarations but the constructor of the class is happily accepting another type of `lambda` in its arguments? are they `cast`able to each other? if yes, why the following makes the compiler sad?

```
// Class stuff...

template<typename T>
void resetActionFn(const T& newFn) { // setter member
    mActionFn = newFn;
}

// Class stuff...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-static data member initialisers only get used if the constructor doesn't specify a different initialiser.

Given

```
struct S {
  int i = 3;
  S() : i(4) { }
};
```

you don't get a default constructor that first initialises `i` to `3`, and then re-initialises it to `4`, you just get a constructor that initialises `i` to `4`.

It's the same with your class. You don't have any constructor that *doesn't* initialise `mActionFn`, so the initialiser doesn't ever get used.

Now, as Piotr S. points out in the comments, in general, the intialiser must still be semantically valid, but your data member has a dependent type, so the validity cannot be checked at template definition time, and the initialiser never gets instantiated since it is unused, so the error goes undetected at instantiation time as well. A similar simpler example is

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
  T x = 3;
  S() : x(0) { }
};
int main() {
  S<void*>();
}
```

which is accepted silently by GCC even though `3` is an invalid initialiser for a field of type `void*`. clang rejects it though. The standard is unclear on whether the instantiation of a template causes the instantiation of any unused NSDMIs, and some compilers instantiate them only as needed. [There is agreement that they *should* be instantiated only as needed, but there are some problems with that approach, which is why not all compilers implement that yet.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1396)

Comment: does this imply the expression used for nsdmi can be invalid? I doubt. It's just like you were trying to have `std::string s = 1;`, saying that it will never be used, since you initialize `s` in every ctor you have

Comment: @PiotrS. Inside a template class, bits get instantiated as needed. For example, given `template <typename T> struct S { void f() { T(); } };`, you can have objects of type `S<void>`, you merely cannot call its `f` member function. Precisely which bits should get instantiated when is still an open question and there is some compiler variation in it.

Comment: because non-virtual member functions of class template are instantiated when required by the context. I don't think this applies for data members. Would be great to provide a Standard reference for that.

Comment: @PiotrS. Found it (not in the standard), added it to my answer.